# corss domain login problem sessionid cookie not set in a django-graphql backend api on aws eb

Tags: django, cookies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apollo, graphene-django

I have setup a `django-graphene` application on `aws eb` successfully but there are authentication problems from cross domain.
Logins are working on same domain but when trying to login from cross domain it do not work.

Using session based authentication (Cookies)

My django-graphql api is on a url something like: http://foo.bar.elasticbeanstalk.com/graphql/

When I login from Insomnia (similar to postman) the login works. This is the response I receive

```js
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 06:36:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8
Vary: Cookie,Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=1FTnBwp8b3OlVVf1NXZqZtWBoZkA1xh4ihryPtvZeTRZj3od5mHn3tDxFhgFvGl9; expires=Thu, 26 Nov 2020 06:36:39 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: sessionid=vv9e1o2m92ekwcaq8xhzoedf9uhues4u; expires=Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:36:39 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Content-Length: 190
Content-Type: application/json
```

In insomnia it works the user is logged in.

On the frontend I am using `gatsby` and `apollo`. The front end is currently running on http://localhost:3000.
This is my Apollo client:

```js
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"
import { fetch } from "isomorphic-fetch"

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://foo.bar.elasticbeanstalk.com/graphql/",
  credentials: "include",
  fetch,
})

export default client
```

When I perform the login mutation no `sessionid` cookie is set. There is also no `csrftoken`.

Login mutation response:

```js
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 271
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 07:39:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=tVvu46tHoRlKgYFoj5g2ybJ6bt6OsahqmqQrCMyNjnAJYBfXO0Z7AGD16nUzM4Vn; expires=Thu, 26 Nov 2020 07:39:06 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=qmze273tr6srktooa7t0y2n9vfyt408h; expires=Thu, 12 Dec 2019 07:39:06 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Vary: Cookie,Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

There is a `Set-Cookie` for `csrftoken` and `sessionid` in response but there are no cookies under `Application -> Cookies -> http://localhost:3000`

My `django-cors-headers` settings are:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = (
    True
)
```

The url.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
]
```

How do I make the login work ?

Comment: I have this identical problem today using Django-GraphQL-Next.js. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Dr J I was unable to setup cross-domain cookie. I started using jwt authentication using https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

OP's issue is the CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS setting in django. The value should not be a tuple but a boolean instead.

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

The following should then be set:

1. CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
2. CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
3. SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
4. CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
5. SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
6. SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
7. CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
   "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
   "http://www.example.com",
   ]
8. CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
   "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
   "http://www.example.com",
   ]

More about these settings on the corsheaders package docs page here: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

On the Apollo Client config make sure to add the **credentials** option as below:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URL,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    credentials: 'include'
  });
```